# Codeigniter how to echo multiple INNER JOIN from same table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, inner-join

I've got two tables **movie** and **director**, in movie's table I've got two fields: '**director1**' and '**director2**'.

With inner join I've match the two table but when I do a foreach of the field 'name' and 'surname' of 'director' I've got only one result, the last one.

This is my model:

```
function getLastMoviesId($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('movie as m');
        $this->db->join('director as d1', 'd1.id = m.director1');
        $this->db->join('director as d2', 'd2.id = m.director2');
        $this->db->where('m.id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
          return $query->result();
        } else {
          return 0;
        }   
    }
```

This is my view:

```
<?php foreach ($archivepage as $m): ?>
  <?= html_entity_decode($m->name) ?>
  <?= html_entity_decode($m->surname) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` matches between the columns in both tables. If both `d1` and `d2` not match, return empty. You can use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Hey thank you for your replay, I've changed `$this->db->join('registi as r1', 'r1.id = f.regista1', 'left');` but the result didn't change, I've got only one result, I think the problem is in the foreach.

Comment: So `var_dump($query->result());` in model. What you get? And you can try `LEFT JOIN` for both `$this->db->join`

Comment: Always one result: `<?php var_dump(html_entity_decode($f->nome)); ?>` return: `string(5) "Marco"`

Comment: try `LEFT JOIN` for both join `$this->db->join`

Comment: My fault, I didn't try `var_dump()` into **model** but into **view**, so if I do that in the model it return `["director1"]=> string(3) "539" ["director2"]=> string(3) "540" ["director3"]=> string(0) ""`.

How can I access to this value?

Comment: var_dump all array to question please.

Comment: `var_dump()` complete: `array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#17 (61) { ["id"]=> NULL ["director1"]=> string(3) "539" ["director2"]=> string(3) "540" ["director3"]=> string(0) "" ["year"]=> NULL } }`

Comment: Your select was all column `*`?

Comment: Yes `$this->db->select('*');`

Comment: Why results haven't name and surname column?

Comment: I've copied the start and the end, I can't copy all the array 'cause it's too long. There's some important part that you want to see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fields values are being over-written as it contains the same names, use something like this instead.

```
$this->db->select('m.*, d1.name d1name, d1.surname d1surname, d2.name d2name, d2.surname d2surname')
$this->db->from('movie as m');
$this->db->join('director as d1', 'd1.id = m.director1', 'left');
$this->db->join('director as d2', 'd2.id = m.director2', 'left');
$this->db->where('m.id', $id);
```

in your view now you can access the values like this

for first one

```
->d1name ->d1surname
```

for second one

```
->d2name ->d2surname
```